# How to alert CPU usage based on % of it. - Datadog

Tags: monitoring, datadog

I'm trying to build an alert for our severs using Datadog based on the % of utilization of the CPU.
At the moment I'm struggling with it, creating alerts based on thresholds numbers would be tricky as not all the servers have the same specs.
I have tried already with some formulas, but they are not giving good results.

Has someone came across the same situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The different CPU specs shouldn't be an issue if you're using % threshold alerts for CPU usage.

The metric you want is `system.cpu.system`

Go to new monitor > metric and specify a threshold type. Then set your warning/alert threshold to whatever CPU% you want to trigger on. Like > 95% CPU for 5 minutes.